# How can you cut a solid bamboo wood plank?

Tags: wood, shelving, circular-saw

I want to buy [SVALNÄS shelves from Ikea](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00322859/) but the widths don't perfectly align with the space. It says these shelves are made of solid bamboo. I've never worked with this material before and was wondering if it's possible to cut with a circular saw or some other tool to fit in the space I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you have says the shelves have a paper honey comb center, not solid. You will not like it if you cut it.